# Angular bootstrap change button colors on click

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="showMoreFunc('academic')" >Academic</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="showMoreFunc('appliedsciences')" >Applied Sciences</button>
```

When we click on the **+** sign, it gives me a panel with 2 buttons. These buttons are set to **default**. But i want to have a function that sets the button to **primary** whenever `clicked`(active), and go back to default when it is `unclicked` or another button is clicked.

How do i achieve this functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `ng-class`, along with the variables you are already setting to toggle display:

```
<button type="button" ng-class="{'btn-primary': display.academic}" ng-click="showMoreFunc('academic')" >Academic</button>
<button type="button" ng-class="{'btn-primary': display.appliedsciences}" ng-click="showMoreFunc('appliedsciences')" >Applied Sciences</button>
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/cAqxxmaS7pjfhfSgCsWL?p=preview

Note: I took a shot at consolidating some of the logic in the `showMoreFunc` function.  I think this works, but your original code worked perfectly well with `ng-class`:

```
$scope.showMoreFunc = function(view) {
  $scope.display.appliedsciences = (view == "appliedsciences" && !$scope.display.appliedsciences);
  $scope.display.academic = (view == "academic" && !$scope.display.academic);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the Buttons (Radio) from http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ :

Change

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="showMoreFunc('academic')" ng-model="academic">Academic</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="showMoreFunc('appliedsciences')" ng-model="appliedsciences">Applied Sciences</button>
```

to

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="showMoreFunc('academic')" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Left'">Academic</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="showMoreFunc('appliedsciences')" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Right'">Applied Sciences</button>
```

and in your controller add

```
$scope.radioModel = 'Left';
```

Result, if btn Academic is 'active'

[image: left]

and this if btn Applied Sciences is 'active'

[image]

Comment: looks great but it doesn't work when i click twice on the same button. the button still remains active.

Comment: I have a problem with thisn since it requires an ngModel ... i dont want that.

Answer (score 1):

I think best way is using pure css to deal with this.

```
.btn:focus{
  outline: 0 !important;  
}
.btn:active  {
  outline:0;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #428bca;
  border-color: #357ebd;
}
```

I wrote a simple plnkr demo with bootstrap 3.1, when you clicking default button, It will change to primary color.

checkout http://plnkr.co/edit/KJR8xL?p=preview

Answer (score -1):

This will work

```
<button type="button" ng-class="{'btn-primary': display.academic}" ng-click="showMoreFunc('academic')" >Academic</button>
<button type="button" ng-class="{'btn-primary': display.appliedsciences}" ng-click="showMoreFunc('appliedsciences')" >Applied Sciences</button>
```